# Does using external RAM work while running predictive models?

Tags: classification, ram, prediction

I am trying to run predictive modeling on large volume of data and this requires large amount of RAM (>8gb which i currently have on my laptop).

Just wanted to check if any of you encountered similar problem ? I recently came across external RAM for windows 7 OS - wondering if any of you have tried it ?

Does it help if i get an "readyboost RAM" of say 25gb or higher to solve this problem ?

Please let me know if its worth investing in external readyboost RAMs ? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I use a 16Gb Memory stick on a 4Gb laptop - Windows 7 will only use 4Gb.. not sure if physical memory and the amount of Readyboost memory that Windows will use are related. I must say it does make a difference. Worth a look with USB memory sticks being so cheap now. 
It certainly seems to speed up program startup and makes the system feel more responsive. A good cheap investment.

Comment: Thats the recommended setting from Windows... when I plugged in the USB stick thats how much it recommended

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/34566/whats-the-maximum-size-windows-7-allows-for-readyboost